# Creating a dynamic XML

Tags: xml, jsp

We have a flash retrieving information from an XML file. Right now we are having to hard code the XML contents and put it at a relative location w.r.t. the flash. Is there any way of making the XML dynamic other than writing to a outputstream to change the stored xml. I want the xml to serve up content just like a JSP.
The approach I can think of is to point the flash to a JSP instead of the XML but we don't have the any flash guys around to do it.
Any suggestions???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can serve xml requests as well (a sample `web.xml` fragment)

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>some your servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then, you can write a HttpServlet that would make a XML Document (I would recommend using `dom4j` for that) and then you will serialize it to out (see `HttpServletRequest.getWriter()`) using `Transformer` (TrAX) api.

You can also serve such requests with jsp, but I wouldn't recommend that. Make a servlet.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply need to update some values in your XML file, it may be best to tokenize some values and have them stored in a properties file, which may be easier to update.

Essentially your XML file would contain lines like:

```
<node value="${name.of.variable}" />
<!-- imagine a large xml file continuing here, most of which doesn't need to be edited  -->
```

and your properties file can contain lines like:

```
name.of.variable="customize this value"
name.of.variable2="customize this value2"
name.of.variable3="customize this value3"
```

Comment: They can't change flash, they can't do that.